# Retrieve the first list item of a sorted list SharePoint 2010 C#

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010

I just started SharePoint webpart programming today. I have list called "pagesList" and I want to order its list items using the field "sortField" in descending order. Then I want to get the first item in the list. here is what I tried so far but I don't know how to get the first item in the sorted list to assign it.

```
if (pagesList != null)
{
    SPQuery q = new SPQuery();
    q.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='sortField' Ascending='False' /></OrderBy>";
    SPListItemCollection listItemCollection = pagesList.GetItems(q);
    CurrentIssueLinkButton.PostBackUrl = /* the first item of the sorted listitems goes here*/;
 }
```

How can I get the first list item?

Answer (score 1):

Set the `RowLimit` of the SPQuery object to one to ensure that at most one item is returned.

Comment: Okay great. Thanks. So, does this mean I can have SPListItem instead of SPListItemCollection?

Comment: @Demi No, it means the collection will have zero or one items in it.  You can then get the first item from that collection using the indexer assuming it actually has at least one item.  You'll need to figure out what you should do if there are no items that are returned.